# Travis CI fails on tsc

Tags: javascript, typescript, github, travis-ci, tsc

So I have a typescript project hosted on github.

I'm trying to set up Travis CI for tests but when I get to the step to compile the code to javascript (tsc command) it fails.

The error looks like this:

```
> node node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
src/DbHandler.ts:2:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './models/User'.
2 import { User, UserInit } from './models/User';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/User.ts:2:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './models/User'.
2 import { User } from "./models/User";
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Found 2 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

The paths to the files ARE correct and it compiles just fine locally..

In the project I have this package.json(cleaned):

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "prod": "node dist/server.js",
    "dev": "ts-node src/server.ts",
    "dev:watch": "nodemon",
    "test:watch": "ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine",
    "test": "node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js --config=jasmine.json"
  },
  "author": "myname",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "~4.17.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "nodemon": "~1.19.4",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "~3.6.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.17.1"
  }
}
```

And my `.travis.yml` looks like:

```
language: node_js
cache: npm
node_js:
  - "stable"

install:
  - npm ci
  - npm run build

script:
  - npm run test
```

And my file structure is something like this:

```
package.json
.travis.yml
src/
    models/
        User.ts
    DbHandler.ts
    User.ts
    server.ts
test/
    files_for_tests_with_ts_extension
```

Comment: Anything? I seem to be in the same boat...

Comment: @der_michael nope.. haven't tried to solve it for a while now since it was a hobby project so the test was more for learning then necessary..

Comment: I fixed my problem by double-checking the capitalization of all file names. Git hat my offending file saved as Example.ts when it was example.ts on the local filesystem. On git checkout it would restore the file with the lowercase e instead of capital E and TypeScript would not find that file anymore. Fixed it with `git mv Example.ts example.ts`.